# Methods and tools to solve the two-temperature model (TTM)

Tags: pde, heat-transfer

I would like to model heat diffusion at the gold / water interface after excitation of the metal surface by an ultrafast laser pulse (ca. 80 fs).

An appropriate model to start with would be the "two temperature model" (TTM) or "parabolic two step" (PTS). This model considers the electronic and lattice systems as separate with electronic and lattice temperature $T_e$ and $T_l$, respectively. The electronic and lattice systems are coupled through an electron-phonon coupling constant $G$ and the electronic system is excited by a source term $S$ representing the incoming laser pulse. The model can be written as two coupled PDEs [from Smith (2001) Appl. Phys. Lett. 78:1240]:
$$
C_e(T_e) \frac{\partial T_e}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( k_e(T_e, T_l) \frac{\partial T_e}{\partial x} \right) - G \left[ T_e - T_l \right] + S \\
C_l \frac{\partial T_l}{\partial t} = G \left[ T_e - T_l \right],
$$
where $C_e$, $C_l$ are electron and lattice heat capacities, respectively, and $k_e$ is the thermal conductivity.

I am specifically interested in determining the temperatures of the system for the first 100 ps.

The question I would like to ask is: What are the different methods and tools available to solve the problem, with an emphasis on entry-level methodologies?

Comment: This should be relatively simple to solve with a one-dimensional finite element method. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you @WolfgangBangerth for you contribution. Finite element is the method I have tried already, which I implemented in Fenics to no success. I would thus like to know about the alternatives, if any.

Comment: Well, "to no success" doesn't give much away. Was it the method that failed? Did you not get along with FEniCS? Are you looking for other methods or other software systems?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Indeed. I didn't want to turn this thread as a support request on FEniCS. If you are interested, though, my latest woes are documented at https://www.allanswered.com/post/wlapm/nonlinearvariationalsolver-converges-with-zero-iteration/

Comment: I would like to use this space to enumerate and document the technics and tools people normally use to solve this type of problems. I am not an expert in the domain and this would be useful to me and, I believe, to others who might in the future be looking for an answer to that.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer. The model does not look complicated to me -- it's just a coupled set of one parabolic equation and an ODE. It's nonlinear but that can be iterated out. Unless $C_e$ and $k_e$ are crazy complicated functions, this does not strike me as a very complicated model.

Comment: I also still don't know what went wrong with your FEniCS implementation. The post you refer to is essentially just a code drop: it does not contain any information what is going wrong, or what you have already done to debug the issue. I can't tell whether it's a problem with FEniCS, your setup, the model, or anything else.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thanks for your comments. You are right, the model itself is not so complicated. $C_e \approx C_e' T_e$ and $k_e \approx k_{eq} T_e / T_l$. The source term (short laser pulse) has no dependency on $T_e$ or $T_l$. The problem most likely lies in my understanding of FEA and my skillset: I am an experimentalist trying to gain insight on his system and data. If an expert would be interested to chime in to solve this problem, his/her contribution would be properly taken in consideration in any resulting publication.

Comment: I will update the linked question on FEniCS AllAnswered (https://www.allanswered.com/post/wlapm/nonlinearvariationalsolver-converges-with-zero-iteration/) with more information and debugging steps later this evening.

Comment: Yes, update the forum post there first. Since you've already invested time in solving this with FEniCS, give them another opportunity to help you figure out what is wrong. I don't think this problem would be terribly difficult to solve in any of the FE libraries, but no need to learn something new if they can help you there.